# How does CiviCRM make the link between uploaded pdfs and the database table?

Tags: pdf

I want to import many pdfs into Civi and so need to make the link between the uploaded pdf and the database table.  I used the UI to upload a sample pdf (calke_walk.pdf) and looking at the db table, the field in question contains an int(10) unsigned   with a value of 8.  The uploaded pdf has a file name of Calke_walk_a0e8f5791bb72c5b53c253f4fa66fd2f.pdf    In Civi's UI the file has a url that ends with &id=8&eid=28308  The clue there is the &id=8 I guess, but is there more to this that I need to know?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [attachment api](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/API+changes#APIchanges-4.6.0:AttachmentAPI), it will handle the nitty-gritty for you.

Comment: I cannot find any examples of the attachment api - and no documentation either apart from your link.  Can you suggest where to look for an example of this api being used in Civi?  Thanks

Comment: In the 4.6+ api explorer (use the demo server if you haven't upgraded) go to the "Code Docs" tab and look it up.